# How to send a video file trough node js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, base64, mp4

I have a node js app that I want to have a file sharing capability. This is the code that takes the file from html input:

```js
var file = document.getElementById('file-selector').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader;
var result = "";
reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
     result = reader.result
    laheta(result, "tilaheta"); // my function to post
})
reader.readAsDataURL(file, 'UTF-8');
```

This is the code in the server side that receives the file data on saves it to folder:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
app.post('/tilaheta', jsonParser, function(req, res){
    var content = req.body.tieto;
    console.log(content);
    var data = content.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
    var buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/FileShare/test", buf, err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
        // file written successfully
      });
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

This works with .txt and .png .jpg, but when I try to do this with video (mp4), it doesnt work. Although the binary data of the received file is almost identical (I haven't found any diferences), the video doesn't play and gives an error. So how can I succesfully send & receive a video file with node js?